# How to set SelectedvaluePath in combobox when the itemsource is a Collection of objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have a Combobox inside a Datagrid in WPF and my DataSource to Datagrid is an Observable Collection of a Class. The Class Contains a List of another class which Contains various properties.

This is how my Observable Collections Looks like

```
public ObservableCollection<TimeLog> Logs
    {
        get
        {
            return _logs;
        }
        set
        {
            _logs = value;
        }
    }
```

And This is the class used behind the Observable Collection

```
public class TimeLog
    {
        private List<Projects> _project;
        public List<Projects> Project
        {
            get
            {
                return _project;
            }
            set
            {
                _project = value;
            }
        }

        private string _taskName;
        public string TaskName
        {
            get
            {
                return _taskName;
            }
            set
            {
                _taskName = value;
            }
        }

        private DateTime _dateSelected;
        public DateTime DateSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _dateSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                _dateSelected = value;
            }
        }

        private double _hoursSpent;
        public double HoursSpent
        {
            get
            {
                return _hoursSpent;
            }
            set
            {
                _hoursSpent = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Empty Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public TimeLog()
        {
            _project = new List<Projects>() { new Projects() };
            _dateSelected = DateTime.Today;
            _taskName = string.Empty;
            _hoursSpent = 0.0;
        }
    }
```

This is my Projects Class..

```
    public class Projects
    {
       private string _projectName;

       public string ProjectName
       {
          get
          {
             return _projectName;
          }
          set
          {
              _projectName = value;
          }
       }

      private DateTime _startDate;
      public DateTime Startdate
      {
        get
        {
            return _startDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
        }
      }


      private DateTime _enddate;
      public DateTime EndDate
      {
        get
        {
            return _enddate;
        }
        set
        {
            _enddate = value;
        }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Could be optional property. But useful for efficient time logging
      /// </summary>
      private double _percentageAllocation;
      public double PercentageAllocation
      {
        get
        {
            return _percentageAllocation;
        }
        set
        {
            _percentageAllocation = value;
        }
      }

      public Projects()
      {
        _projectName = string.Empty;
        _startDate = DateTime.Today;
        _enddate = DateTime.Today;
        _percentageAllocation = 0.0;
      }
}
```

And This is how my XAML looks like.

```
 <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Project Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Name="cbProjects" ItemsSource="{Binding Project}" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.ComboSelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource covert},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Allocation">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="tbAllocation" Text="{Binding DataContext.ComboSelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource covert},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TaskName}" Header="Task Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HoursSpent}" Header="Hours Spent"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The Combobox placed inside the datagrid needs to be bound with the SelectedvaluePath property to the AllocationPercentage Property of the Projects Class. I have tried numerous times but ran out of luck with this. Can someone guide what needs to done in these scenarios and kindly correct me if I have done anything wrong in this implementation.

**What I Need to accomplish is that whenever I am selecting the value of the Combobox(Since Combobox is a of type Projects), I need to bind that selected value(preferably AllocationPercentage) in the textblock below.**

Comment: It's a little hard to see what's actually happening here. Where does `DataContext.ComboSelectedItem` come from and what does your `covert` converter look like?

Comment: What is the datacontext of the parent(s) of your datagrid? You define `ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}"` but we don't know what the datacontext is. Make sure there is a datacontext assigned to the page or datagrid (either in wpf or codebehind), for example `<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Logs}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ... >`

Comment: Selected value path is a string. Just give it the name of the property.

Comment: @RobbieVercammen I have added a para at the end to describe what I am expecting things to happen. Can you help further?

Comment: @RobbieVercammen the Converter I have placed just to debug. and the Datacontext is referring to the window's datacontext.

Comment: @RobbieVercammen Also I have changed the way of reading the DataContext in my code, but still I am facing some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your grid to update when a value changes but you haven't implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You have an `ObservableCollection` but your `TimeLog` class has no observable properties.

```
public class TimeLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // extra property for the selected project
    private Projects _selectedProjects 
    public Projects SelectedProjects
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_selectedProjects == null && _project.Any())
            {
                _selectedProjects = _project.First();
            }
            return _selectedProjects;
        };
        set
        {
             _selectedProjects = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("_SelectedProjects");
        };
    }
    List<Projects> _project;

    // Ommited the rest

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Because this is my preffered way, you could rearrange your WPF like this:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Project Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbProjects" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Project}" SelectedItem="{Binding Projects}" SelectionChanged="OnMyComboBoxChanged" >
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Allocation">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="tbAllocation" DataContext="{Binding SelectedProjects}" Text="{Binding AllocationPercentage"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And in c#

```
private void OnMyComboBoxChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var cbb = (ComboBox)sender;
    var projects= (Projects)cbb.SelectedItem;
    var timeLog = (TimeLog)cbb.DataContext;

    timeLog.SelectedProjects = projects;
}
```

I think that's the direction you want to go to.
This was written from the top of my head so sorry for any compilation errors :)

Comment: Thanks.I will let you know once i have implemented the suggested changes

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help :)